# What filesystem can I use for a large amount of small-sized data?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, hfs+, exfat

I was copying ~3.7TB of data from one 4TB external drive with HFS+ filesystem, to another 4TB external drive with an exFAT filesystem. The new HDD got filled after only ~75% of the data could be transferred, due to, I am guessing, the allocation unit size of exFAT using up more space per file for small file sizes.

I am copying a lot (~ millions) of small files (1.5kB each). So I am trying to figure out how to do this.

Therefore I need a filesystem that fullfills the following requirements:

- Block size small enough that I can fit millions of files sized 1.5kB wasting minimal space. (here exFAT has a problem)
- Read/write compatible with Linux. (here HFS+ has a problem)
- Able to make a 4T partition on Linux. (here ext4 has problems)

Any alternative filesystem?

**UPDATE:** This question was flagged as already been answered in another post ([Optimizing file system for lots of small files?](https://superuser.com/questions/1181868/optimizing-file-system-for-lots-of-small-files)). However the accepted answer does not work for me:

```
mkfs.ext4 -b 1024 /dev/your_partition

Warning: specified blocksize 1024 is less than device physical sectorsize 4096
/dev/sdc: Cannot create filesystem with requested number of inodes while setting up superblock
```

Comment: EXT4 has no problem creating 4TB partitions.

Comment: IMHO the best filesystem is [ZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS) that has many advantages over others, it well supported on all BSDs and Linux and even on windows (in early betas). If you want to be more compatible, then microsoft's NTFS will do the job over `ntfs-3g`, it can be accessible practically on any platforms. Do not use exFAT for sure, basically it is old FAT32 system but with removed maximum limits, that doesn't support any integrity checking as well wasting space by using huge cluster size.

Comment: One more for zfs

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia the problem is the tiny files, not the volume size. \@hirschme the maximum volume size for ex4 is 1EiB. See [filesystem for millions of small files](https://serverfault.com/q/6711/343888), [What is the most high-performance Linux filesystem for storing a lot of small files (HDD, not SSD)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28756/44425), [Optimizing file system for lots of small files?](https://superuser.com/q/1181868/241386), [Filesystem large number of files in a single directory](https://serverfault.com/q/43133/343888). But you should clarify if your files are 150 or 1.5kB

Comment: @phuclv thanks for the suggestion, I corrected the file size in the question and updated with the possible duplicate post

Comment: @phuclv I know. I wasn't intending to answer the actual question, just correcting the part "make a 4T partition ... here ext4 has problems". It hasn't

Comment: `Warning: specified blocksize 1024 is less than device physical sectorsize 4096` means the disk is 4K and it's impossible to create a partition with block size smaller than that. A file system with block suballocation is required

Comment: zipping, creating large archive an option?

Comment: @phuclv Note the word "Warning" in that message. It's not saying you can't do it; it's just making sure you know performance may be impacted. The real reason your command is rejected is what it complains about afterward: the number of inodes. Apparently, there are too many, so you'll need to reduce the number in some way. See the documentation for the appropriate options, as you want to be sure you strike a balance between hogging space with too many and running out because you have too few (each file has an associated inode).

Answer (score 8):

Files systems that you can use

- Ones that support some kind of [block suballocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_suballocation). There are many forms of this like

  - *block subdivision*: divide a block into two multiple times
  - *tail packing*: share the last partial block of multiple files in a block
  - *variable block size*: allows merging or dividing blocks

  Some filesystems with block suballocation: [ReiserFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReiserFS), [Reiser4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reiser4), [JFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JFS_%28file_system%29), [NWFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetWare_File_System), [ZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS), [Btrfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs), [UFS1/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_File_System), [VMFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_VMFS)... For example [VMFS5/6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_VMFS) has block size of 1 MB but have [*Support of small files of 1 KB*](https://www.reflections-ibs.com/blog/articles/vmfs5-or-vmfs6)
- Ones that support [resident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Resident_vs._non-resident_attributes)/[inline](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Inline_Data) files like NTFS, ext4 or Btrfs

However given the scale of your problem which involves *millions of files*, ReiserFS/Reiser4, Btrfs and ZFS may be the best solution

For more details read below

---

Since your files are around 1.5 KB, the ***ideal*** block size for your case would be 512-byte. However your disk has **4 KB physical sector size** (A.K.A [Advanced Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format)) as can be seen from the error message:

> Warning: specified blocksize 1024 is less than device physical sectorsize 4096

which means **you can't create a block size smaller than that**. You need to use block suballocation to reduce wasted space. You can open [Comparison of file systems - Allocation and layout policies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Allocation_and_layout_policies) and sort on *Block suballocation / Tail packing / Variable block size* to know which file systems support such features

[image: Allocation and layout policies]

---

Another alternative is to **store data in metadata space** where multiple records is allocated into a single block

In NTFS each file is represented by an [MFT record](http://ntfs.com/ntfs-mft.htm) which is the analog of [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) in *nix. Files that are small will be stored in the MFT record directly, saving space and also improving access time because you don't need another disk read to get the real data. Those are called [resident files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Resident_vs._non-resident_attributes). Later in ext4 a similar feature was added and called [inline files](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Inline_Data):

> The inline data feature was designed to handle the case that a file's data is so tiny that it readily fits inside the inode, which (theoretically) reduces disk block consumption and reduces seeks. If the file is smaller than 60 bytes, then the data are stored inline in `inode.i_block`.

The 60-byte value is for the default inode size of 256-byte. The inode structure consumes 156 bytes and the other 40 bytes may be for some extended feature. However you can [change the inode size](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Inode_Size) to 2 KB to fit all of your 1.5 KB files with the [`-I inode-size` option](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mke2fs.8.html) while formatting

In Btrfs there's also a similar feature where small files are written directly into the metadata stream

> **`max_inline=bytes`**
>
> ( default: min(2048, page size) )
>
> Specify the maximum amount of space, that can be inlined in a metadata B-tree leaf. The value is specified in bytes, optionally with a K suffix (case insensitive).
>
> https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs(5)

It seems [Reiser4 also has such a feature](https://reiser4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Why_Reiser4) although I can't confirm it.

In NTFS the current default MFT record is 1 KB although it was 4 KB in NTFS 1.0 in Windows NT 3.1. That only allows files around 600-900 bytes or less to be resident so you'll have to change the MFT record size. [It's possible](http://kcall.co.uk/ntfs/index.html) although you'll have a hard time finding a formatting software that allows changing the default MFT record size

Some people have roughly the same situation as yours

- [Millions of small files: best filesystem / best options](https://mailing.freebsd.fs.narkive.com/uViFfqiD/millions-of-small-files-best-filesystem-best-options)
- [filesystem for millions of small files](https://serverfault.com/q/6711/343888)
- [What is the most high-performance Linux filesystem for storing a lot of small files (HDD, not SSD)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28756/44425)

---

There are also many misunderstandings from your side

> Read/write compatible with Linux. (here HFS+ has a problem)

There are many read/write HFS+ drivers in Linux available, so this shouldn't be a problem. The only issue with HFS+ is that it's in the same era as ext2 so it's far more inferior compared to modern file systems like ext4, NTFS, ZFS or Btrfs

> Able to make a 4T partition on Linux. (here ext4 has problems)

Neither ext4 nor exFAT has issue creating a 4 TB partition with 1 KB block size. In fact **any 32-bit filesystem can create a 4 TB volume with 1 KB block size** because 2<sup>32</sup> blocks × 2<sup>10</sup> bytes/block = 4 × 2<sup>40</sup> bytes = 4 TB, and with the default 4 KB block size then the maximum partition size is 16 TB. ext4 uses 48-bit address, thus has much bigger maximum size

> Block size small enough that I can fit millions of files sized 1.5kB wasting minimal space. (here exFAT has a problem)

In fact the only issue with exFAT is that [the default block size is too big](https://superuser.com/a/1273226/241386). The minimum block size on exFAT is **1 sector** so it can have 512-byte block size in a disk with 512-bit sector (See [*9.2 Cluster Size Limits*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/exfat-specification#9-file-system-limits) in the spec). You can see 512-byte and 1 KB options in the format dialog as below. Unfortunately your disk has 4 KB sector so exFAT doesn't work

[image: exFAT block sizes in format dialog]

[image: exFAT block sizes]

Answer (score -2):

"Able to make a 4T partition on Linux. (here ext4 has problems)"

**Ext4 don't have any problem with 4TB partition.**

```
~# LANG=C; df -hT |grep T
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1      ext4       33T   12T   20T  37% /RAIDDATA
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Submitting as comment would have been more appropriate IMO.

Comment: read my comments in the question, the problem is the **tiny files**, not the *volume size*